Maximisation of product
a , b are real numbers such that $2a^2 + 5b^2 = 20$. Then the maximum value of $a^4b^6$ is..
I tried to solve it through the Arithmetic mean $\geq$ Geometric mean principle.
So we suppose
$$
\begin{aligned}
x= 2a^2 &,y= 5b^2\\
\text{Then } \dfrac{x+y}{2}&= \dfrac{2a^2+5b^2}{2}\geq\sqrt{2a^25b^2}\\
\sqrt{2a^25b^2}&\leq 10\\
ab\sqrt{10}&\leq10, ab\leq \sqrt{10}\\
\text{Then,   } & a^4b^4\leq100
\end{aligned}
$$
To maximise the value of $ab$ if we consider that $x=y$ then $2a^2= 5b^2$ and $b^2=2$.
Thus $a^4b^4\times b^2= a^4b^6= 200$. However, my answer doesn't correspond to any of the available choices which are,

256
1024
1262
16


Not following your computation.  Why are you maximizing $ab$?  If we take $a=2$ then we have $b^2=\frac {20-2a^2}{5}=\frac {12}5=2.4$ and $a^4b^6=221.184$ which is larger than your value.

Should say:  that's what I see as the max which, again, isn't one of the options.  My method was just to substitute for $b$ to get $f(a)=a^4\times b(a)^6$ and then maximized that as a function of $a$.  That is, I used the constraint to get this to a function in one variable

Then consider the AM and GM of $\left(3a^2, 3a^2, 5b^2, 5b^2, 5b^2\right)$?

Your attempt is interesting, but you maximized $a^4 b^4$ and just assumed that the maximum for $b$ in that scenario must be the same as for maximizing $a^4 b^6$. A counterexample was already posted in the comments.
If we graph the function
$$
f(x,y) = x^4 y^6
$$
and restrict its domain to the $(x,y)$ such that
$$
g(x,y) = 2x^2+5y^2 \le 20
$$
you can see that it will exceed $200$ sometimes.

Meanwhile, for
$$
h(x,y) = x^4 y^4
$$
clearly it seems to not surpass $100$.

(Desmos demo link.)

So, how would one solve it?
Honestly, outside of being clever, I'm not sure how to work with it other than brute force with calculus, along these lines:

Consider the equation $2x^2+5y^2=20$ in the $x,y$ plane. Develop a parameterization for that curve. (There's a standard parameterization of ellipses.) Let's call the parameterization $\gamma(t)$.

Then $f(x,y) = x^4 y^6$ takes values $f(\gamma(t))$ for $x,y$ on said ellipse.

Naturally, then, one can find $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} f(\gamma(t))$, set it equal to zero, and apply standard optimization tests.


I only go over the details briefly since:

For one, if you're a calculus-or-higher-level student, these techniques are probably very basic to you and the overarching process suffices.

For another, though, I suspect you're not in calculus or the techniques of calculus are forbidden (hence the use of AM-GM), and I honestly don't know what I'd do in your situation if that's the case. Maybe someone will have more useful advice in that respect for you, or an approach using more elementary techniques. (Indeed, I originally intended this as an extended comment for that reason.)



By a similar principle, consider the AM and GM of $\left(3a^2, 3a^2, 5b^2, 5b^2, 5b^2\right)$:
$$\begin{align*}
GM &\le AM\\
\sqrt[5]{\left(3a^2\right)^2\left(5b^2\right)^3} &\le \frac{2\cdot 3a^2 +3\cdot 5b^2}{5}\\
\sqrt[5]{3^2 5^3 a^4b^6} &\le \frac{3\left(2a^2+5b^2\right)}{5}= 3\cdot 4\\
a^4b^6 &\le \frac{3^34^5}{5^3} = 221.184
\end{align*}$$
Equality holds when $3a^2=5b^2$:
$$\begin{align*}
2a^2 + 5b^2 &= 20\\
2a^2 + 3a^2 &= 20\\
a^2 &= 4\\
b^2 &= \frac{3\cdot 4}{5} = 2.4\\
a^4b^6 &= 221.184
\end{align*}$$
Comparing this maximum with your candidate, here $a^4b^4 = 92.16 < 100$ but $b^2 = 2.4 > 2$, and it happens that the product $a^4b^6 > 200$.

Two alternate methods:
I.  Reduce to a single variable.  Since $b^2=\frac {20-2a^2}5$ we can simply maximize the function $$f(a)=a^4\times \left(\frac {20-2a^2}5\right)^3$$
If you like you can substitute $x=a^2$ to lower the degree.
II Lagrange multipliers.  We seek to solve $$(4a^3b^6, 6a^4b^5)=\lambda (4a, 10b)$$  Which comes to $$4a^3b^6=4\lambda a\implies \lambda =a^2b^6$$ and $$6a^4b^5=10\lambda b\implies \lambda = \frac 35 a^4b^4$$
Since, of course, the max can't occur where either $a,b=0$.
We deduce that $$\frac 35a^4b^4=a^2b^2\implies \frac 35 a^2=b^2$$ after which the computation is easy.
In both cases we get $a=\pm 2$ at the max, for a value of $221.184$
Worth noting, perhaps, that this isn't one of the available options.
